# What User-Agent string does Android send in rtsp requests?

Tags: android, rtsp

Does the User-Agent string vary across different devices or is it the same everywhere? Are the ClientID, CompanyID, etc strings the same?

Here's what I get from the emulator over http:

```
User-Agent: stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 4.1.1)
```

Answer (score -1):

This site seems to have nice coverage:

http://www.gtrifonov.com/2011/04/15/google-android-user-agent-strings-2/

Comment: Those are HTTP User-Agent strings, and are for requests from WebViews not MediaPlayers.